# Overriding material-ui css in subcomponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the `right` attribute of the `expandIcon` in an `ExpansionPannel`:

```
  <ExpansionPanel>
    <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
      <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
      <Typography>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
        sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
      </Typography>
    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
  </ExpansionPanel>
```

By default, `ExpandMoreIcon` is rendered with an attribute `right` of `8px`. I want to change that to `-8px` so I tried:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    expandIcon: {
        right: "-8px"
    }
})
...

<ExpansionPanelSummary 
    className={classNames(classes.myCustomClass, {expandIcon: classes.expandIcon})} 
    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
>
```

I also need this `myCustomClass`.

But this does not override the css. Also, setting `<ExpandMoreIcon style={{right: "-8px"}}/>` does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, it's in a typo!

I had to pass the overridden class to the `classes` prop and not the `className`!

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary 
    className={classes.myCustomClass}
    classes={{expandIcon: classes.expandIcon}} 
    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
>
```